# Loading wont show up on ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am using the jQuery below in an autocomplete input field.

Now, I'd like for a spinner to show up while the ajax is waiting for the response from the server.

I am using `search:` to show the loading div. And then `open:` to hide it. And finally success to display the result.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#search_field').keyup(function(){  
           var search = $(this).val();  
           if(search != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({

                     url: 'search.php',  
                     method: 'POST',  
                     data: {search:search},  

                     search: function()
                     {
                         $('#search_loader').fadeIn('fast', 'swing');
                     },

                     open: function()
                     {
                         $('#search_loader').fadeOut('fast', 'swing');
                     },

                     success: function(data)  
                     {     
                         if(data == '') {
                             $('#autocomplete_result').fadeOut('fast', 'swing');
                         } else {
                             $('#autocomplete_result').fadeIn('fast', 'swing'); 
                             $('#autocomplete_result').html(data); 
                         }
                     }


                });  
           }  
      });  


 });
```

However neither `search:` or `open:` work.

New with JS, so can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a jquery plugin for autocomplete?

Comment: @Bommox Yes I am.

Comment: what is search and open? Seems that you use jQuery for Ajax, but both mentioned function do not exist there! What would be to use `beforeSend` and & `done`?

Comment: We need to know which library are you using. What you typed is not the jquery ajax function.

Comment: @Bommox I've just posted the entire function. Please take a look.

Comment: @elsololobo Well while it's posting and waiting to receive the data, I'd like to show a loader. Once it's done I'd want it to hide the loader and simultaneously show the data.

Comment: Can you mention exactly which jquery plugin you are trying to implement here?

Comment: @shanthi_karthika I am using this version `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js`. No other plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . There is no open and search options .Try to use beforeSend and complete ,also set `fadeIn fadeOut` to "slow"

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#search_field').keyup(function(){  
           var search = $(this).val();  
           if(search != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({    
                     url: 'search.php',  
                     method: 'POST',  
                     data: {search:search},    
                     beforeSend : function()
                     {
                         $('#search_loader').fadeIn('slow', 'swing');
                     },   
                     complete : function()
                     {
                         $('#search_loader').fadeOut('slow', 'swing');
                     },

                     success: function(data)  
                     {     
                         if(data == '') {
                             $('#autocomplete_result').fadeOut('fast', 'swing');
                         } else {
                             $('#autocomplete_result').fadeIn('fast', 'swing'); 
                             $('#autocomplete_result').html(data); 
                         }
                     }
                });  
           }  
      });  
 });
```

Comment: `success:` works. The `complete:` and `before` wont work. What could be causing a problem?

Comment: If your `#search_loader` is not showing in browser , it is working

Comment: it´s not `before` -> `beforeSend` as far as I know. Just read the doc´s

Answer (score 0):

Ajax have the following syntax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_url',
    method: 'get', // or post
    data: {
        var1 : val1,
        var2 : val2
    },
    before:  function(){

    },
    onComplete: function(){

    },
    success : function(response){

    }
});
```

There is no search: function() defined. If required you can call them in 
**before()**
or
**onComplete()**

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer, doesn't it?

Comment: I tried that, wont work... I showed the div in `before` and hid it `onComplete`.